# Using tar on SLES Linux

Tags: linux, tar, sles, sles10, sles11

I am trying to install some package from these instructions:

http://www.franz.com/agraph/support/documentation/v4/server-installation.html#header3-25

I run this command:

```
tar zxf agraph-4.2-linuxamd64.64.tar.gz
```

and get this error:

```
tar: agraph-4.2-linuxamd64.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors
```

Any idea why this may happen and how I can make it work?  Thanks!

Comment: Based on error message you've shown, you're passing agraph-4.2.linux64.tar.gz to tar. Correct file name has another ".64" in the middle (as shown in Bryan's answer).

Comment: A typical "trick" in such cases is to copy the file name an paste if after an `ls ` command (like `ls agraph-4.2-linuxamd64.64.tar.gz`). If the error is "No such file or directory" you know what the error is. Usually the commands are right. You could also use `strace tar zxf agraph-4.2-linuxamd64.64.tar.gz` to see what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you've downloaded the file yet, or you're not in the directory that you downloaded the file to, or the file you're trying to open has a different name than what's specified in the instructions. Do an 'ls', do you see the file there?

I was able to download the file and untar it successfully:

```
bryan@velouria:~$ mkdir test
bryan@velouria:~$ cd test
bryan@velouria:~/test$ wget http://www.franz.com/products/allegrograph/download/dist-sa/linuxamd64.64.4/agraph-4.2-linuxamd64.64.tar.gz
--2011-05-04 17:35:02--  http://www.franz.com/products/allegrograph/download/dist-sa/linuxamd64.64.4/agraph-4.2-linuxamd64.64.tar.gz
Resolving www.franz.com... 67.207.112.67
Connecting to www.franz.com|67.207.112.67|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 84235718 (80M) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: `agraph-4.2-linuxamd64.64.tar.gz'
100%[============================================================================================>] 84,235,718   708K/s   in 2m 2s   
bryan@velouria:~/test$ ls
agraph-4.2-linuxamd64.64.tar.gz
bryan@velouria:~/test$ tar zxf agraph-4.2-linuxamd64.64.tar.gz 
bryan@velouria:~/test$ ls
agraph-4.2  agraph-4.2-linuxamd64.64.tar.gz
bryan@velouria:~/test$ ls agraph-4.2/
aclissl.so      ag4-import.dxl  agload.rc          agraph-control      agraph-recover.lic    binary-license.txt  convertdb      gpl.txt         sort-upi-map
ag3-export      ag4-import.lic  agraph             agraph.dxl          agraph-recover.rc     checkdb             convertdb.dxl  install-agraph  templates
ag3-export.dxl  ag4-import.rc   agraph-backup      agraph.lic          agraph-replicate      checkdb.dxl         convertdb.lic  libacli8218.so  www
ag3-export.lic  agload          agraph-backup.dxl  agraph.rc           agraph-replicate.dxl  checkdb.lic         convertdb.rc   liblzo2.so.2
ag3-export.rc   agload.dxl      agraph-backup.lic  agraph-recover      agraph-replicate.lic  checkdb.rc          doc            locales
ag4-import      agload.lic      agraph-backup.rc   agraph-recover.dxl  agraph-replicate.rc   configure-agraph    files.bu       sendfd.so
bryan@velouria:~/test$
```